# Create node by post Api call fail with message "Could not determine entity type bundle: \\u0022type\\u0022 field is missing."}

Tags: 9

I'm trying to create a node via Drupal API but I get this error:

```
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://site.it/entity/node?_format=hal_json` resulted in a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response:\n{"message":"Could not determine entity type bundle: \\u0022type\\u0022 field is missing."}
```

This is my function:

```
public function createFaq($notes, $telegram_id){
  $url = "/entity/node?_format=hal_json"; 
  $opt = [
    'headers' => self::$baseHeader,
    'body' => json_encode([
      [
        'type' => [ ['target_id' => 'faq'] ],
        'title' => 'title', 
        'utente' => [ [ 'target_id' => '123462' ] ],
        'field_domanda' => [ [ 'value' => $notes['domanda'] ] ],
        'field_presenza' => [ [ 'value' => $notes['presenza'] == "Si"? true : false ] ],
      ]
    ])
  ];

  $response = $this->client->request('POST', $url , $opt);
  $r = json_decode( $response->getBody());
  return $r; 
}
```

But it's really strange, because this other function is working:

```
public static function createUser($title){
  $url= "/entity/node?_format=hal_json"; 
  $opt = [
    'headers' => self::$baseHeader,
    'body' => json_encode([
      'title' => [ [ 'value' => $title ] ],
      'type' => [ [ 'target_id' => 'article' ] ],
    ])
  ];

  $response = $this->client->request('POST', $url , $opt);
  $r = json_decode( $response->getBody());
  return $r; 
}
```

Can someone understood my error?

Comment: Your second (working) example has this POST body `['type' => ...]` whereas the first example has it wrapped in an additional array: `[['type' => ...]]`.

Comment: You are right!! Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used to create a node using rest api:

Endpoint: `/node?_format=hal_json`

Method: `POST`

Body:

```
{
  "title": [
    {
      "value": "This is a question"
    }
  ],
  "field_question": [
    {
      "value": "This is the question"
    }
  ],
  "field_options": [
    {
      "value": "This is the right option"
    },
    {
      "value": "This is not the right option"
    },
    {
      "value": "This is defenitely not the right option"
    },
    {
      "value": "This is the most silly option"
    }
  ],
  "type": [
    {
      "target_id": "question"
    }
  ]
}
```

Enable the [Rest UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/restui) module to check if the endpoint exists. Actually I can't find the plugin proposing this endpoint but having Rest UI enabled I saw this URI for posting content types.